# Mongoose $pull not removing element from db

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to remove an entry from an array and essentially move it into another array in the same collection by doing a $pull and $push. $push is working fine as expected, but $pull fails to remove the array element.

This is the code that I have. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
var delete_this = save.one;

X.findOne({
    "_id": new ObjectId(y)
}, function(err, doc){

    var z;
    for (var i = 0; i < doc.requests.length; i++){
        if (doc.requests[i].userId == delete_this){
            z = doc.requests[i];
            break;
        }
    }

    doc.requests.pull({ "userId": delete_this });
    doc.terminate.push(request);
    doc.save();
});
```

This is  the actual object inside the array that I want removed. Should clear things up even more.

```
"requests" : [ 
        {
            "userId" : "56705fa2e7cd4c13519e08e5",
            "userRating" : null,
            "userImage" : "56705fa2e7cd4c13519e08e5",
            "name" : "Sunil"
        }
    ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem and this worked for me. All I had to do was call .remove on the array of ObjectIds, and pass in the id I wanted to remove and that did the trick.

```
doc.requests.remove(idToRemove);
```

You can update your code like so and try it out.

```
X.findOne({
    "_id": new ObjectId(y)
}, function(err, doc){
    //I'm not sure what z is doing....
    var z;
    for (var i = 0; i < doc.requests.length; i++){
        if (doc.requests[i].userId == delete_this){
            z = doc.requests[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    //this should be all you need
    doc.requests.remove(delete_this);
    doc.terminate.push(request);
    doc.save();
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. It still doesnt work for me. I have updated the question with the mongo subdocument i want to remove. Can you please take a look and confirm if I am doing things correctly? Thanks again.